# Function Insertion from a For... in Loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, loops

Issue: A function I have not declared is attaching to a variable's memory space I have never assigned it to?

Backstory: I have a script I've built to remove duplicate objects by referencing comparing the value of object keys.  After the initialization of the `checkSum` variable and the immediately following `For...in loop` a "ghost" value of the function goodDiver is added to the variable `k`?

```
'use strict';

const goodDiver = require('good-diver');

// This package uses good-diver to make things simple :) 
// Read more about it here: https://github.com/starcrusherproductions/good-diver

/**
 * 
 * @param {object} object object you want to truncate
 * @param {array} keysToCheck array of the key's path using good-diver
 * @param {array} keyMustBe array consition of boolean values of what corresponding keysToCheck must be. 
 */

function goodRemover(object, keysToCheck, keyMustBe = Array(keysToCheck.length).fill(true)) { 

  // Initialize c as a count to cycle through the filter later on
  let c = 0;

  // Pump the data into a reference variable
  let reference = object.map(r => {

    // Initialize an empty array to store the keys of duplicates
    let keys = [];

    // Create an iteratable data object call it iterator
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries
    let iterator = object.entries();

    // Iterate through the data object to find the keys
    for (let i of iterator) {

      // THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS?

      // Create an array called checkSum.  We will see if checkSum[0].length===checkSum[1].length
      let checkSum = [keysToCheck,[]];

      // Debug: Expected result: object [ 'teamName', 'teamId' ] 2
      console.log(typeof(checkSum[0]), checkSum[0], checkSum[0].length);
      // Returned Result: object [ 'teamName', 'teamId' ] 2

      // For each keysToCheck in checkSum[0] 
      for(let k in keysToCheck) {

        // Simplify set keysToCheck[k] to key for simplification
        let key = keysToCheck[k];

        // Debug expected result: string, k
        console.log(typeof(key), k);

        /**
         * Returned: 
         *  string 0
         *  string 1
         *  function goodDiver
         */

        // ^^^ END OF PROBLEM???

        // For object iteration does any of 
        if((i[1].goodDiver(key) === r.goodDiver(key)) === keyMustBe[k] ){

          // Yes push a value to the checkSum 
          checkSum[1].push(true)
        }

      }

      // Does object iteration match a schema?
      if(checkSum[0].length===checkSum[1].length) {

        // Yes push it's keys i[0] into the tracker
        keys.push(i[0]);

      }
    }

    // Return the object keys
    return { keys }
  })

  // Now map through the reference object
  .map(r => {

    // Does object iteration of the reference have more than 1 key?
    if(r.keys.length>1 && r.keys[0]===c) {

      // Yes.  Increment the counter and return just the first element
      c++;
      return r.keys[0];

    }

    // It does not
    else {

      // Increment c.  Return nothing.
      c++;
    }
  })
  // The nature of map returns undefined if there is nothing to return
  // We need to filter out the undefineds and just return stuff that isn't undefined
  .filter(r => {

    // Return boolean test
    return r!=null;
  });

  /**
  * Initialize a new array and iterate through reference to 
  * return data sets that match conditions in reference
  */

  // 
  let newData = [];

  //
  for(let r in reference) {

    newData.push(object[reference[r]]);

  }
  return newData;
}


let objectWithDuplicates = [
  {
    id: 1,
    teamId: 1,
    franchiseId: 2,
    teamName: 'Gulls' 
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    teamId: 1,
    franchiseId: 2,
    teamName: 'Gulls' 
  }]

goodRemover(objectWithDuplicates,['teamName','teamId']);
```

The reference to goodDiver is one of my other packages, [good-diver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/good-diver).  If I remove the dependency it does not assign itself to k.  This `for... in loop` is the only place `goodDiver` is called.  It is not assigned to any values.  It also has no variables declared under the name of k.  It does; however, work on the object prototype.

That conditional statement is the only place goodDiver is executed.  Even weirder if I comment that conditional execution out goodDiver still is attached to k?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Got that updated now.  Should be enough to download and replicate the experience.

Comment: "*[...] though left out the package dependency source code*" - which makes this code incomplete. Besides, the code you posted is not minimal. You shouldn't need more than 20 or 30 lines to demonstrate a specific problem.

Comment: @melpomene I originally posted a snippet of the section which I diagnosed to cause the issue and after thorough testing was dumbfounded by the results.  You requested more.  So I posted the entire module with the listed dependencies.  I described the issue I was having clearly and concisely.  I apologize for any confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your ghost function comes from a prototype chain (for..in loop iterates over the whole chain). You can try to use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` or `Object.entries()` instead.

Comment: This explanation just blew my mind but if I understand correctly because I ran `r.goodDiver() || i[1].goodDiver()` it then attaches the goodDiver function to the prototype chain.  Which then attempts to iterate over it inside of the for... in for the keysToCheck?

Comment: Well, for.. in loop is very thorough and it indeed iterates over the whole prototype chain. Try to `console.log` or `console.dir` your keysToCheck object and traverse the prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't a direct answer to your problem, it looks like you could achieve your desired functionality much more easily with [lodash](https://lodash.com/). `get` performs the same thing as your included library, and `uniqWith` performs the filtering. For example:

```js
 let objectWithDuplicates = [
   {
     id: 1,
     teamId: 1,
     franchiseId: 2,
     teamName: 'Gulls' 
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     teamId: 1,
     franchiseId: 2,
     teamName: 'Gulls' 
   }
 ]
    
 const getComparer = keys => (a, b) => {
   return keys.every(k => _.get(a, k) === _.get(b, k))
 }
    
 const result = _.uniqWith(objectWithDuplicates, getComparer(['teamName', 'teamId']))
 
 console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.6/lodash.min.js"></script>
```